# swift 4 Firebase Database - ObserveSingleEvent for .value returns Null even though data exists

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I did find a couple of duplicate posts for this occurrence but none of the answers seem to apply to my situation.

I'm running the following code:

```
    let dbRef = Database.database().reference()
    guard let myUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }

    print("Statistics:  initializeStatistics:  dbRef object", dbRef.description())

    userRef = dbRef.child("users").child(myUser.uid)
    appStatsRef = dbRef.child("Stats/AppStats").child(myUser.uid)
    globalStatsRef = dbRef.child("Stats/GlobalStats").child(myUser.uid)
    locationStatsRef = dbRef.child("Stats/LocationStats")

    if let appRef = appStatsRef {
        print("Statistics:  initializeStatistics:  Setting Up Single Event observation. Ref=",appRef.description())

        appRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("Statistics: SingleObservation from:  Ref: ", appRef)
            print("Statistics: SingleObservation:  Initial State of AppStats: ", snapshot)
            }) {
                (error) in
                print("Statistics: SingleObservation:  Error: ",error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

The log messages that I see are:

```
Statistics:  initializeStatistics:   UserId:  zo9KcrXXXXXXXmSv8Cc8W2XeCb2
Statistics:  initializeStatistics:  dbRef object https://bxxxxxxx-30999.firebaseio.com
Statistics:  initializeStatistics:  Setting Up Single Event observation. Ref= https://bxxxxxxx-30999.firebaseio.com/Stats/AppStats/zo9KcrXXXXXXXmSv8Cc8W2XeCb2
Statistics: SingleObservation from:  Ref:  https://bxxxxxxx-30999.firebaseio.com/Stats/AppStats/zo9KcrXXXXXXRXmSv8Cc8W2XeCb2
Statistics: SingleObservation:  Initial State of AppStats:  Snap (zo9KcrXXXXXXXmSv8Cc8W2XeCb2) <null>
```

Inside my Firebase Database, I have the following structure and data:

```
{
  "Stats" : {
    "AppStats" : {
      "zo9KcrXXXXXXXmSv8Cc8W2XeCb2" : {
        "ctime" : 1.531419079915515E9,
        "dateFirstTaggedTicket" : 1.531419079470825E12,
        "dateLastTaggedTicket" : 1.531419079470825E12,
        "disabledHotballSupport" : false,
        "firstGamePlayed" : 0,
        "gamesCompleted" : 0,
        "gamesContinuedAfterWin" : 0,
        "gamesPlayed" : 0,
        "gamesPlayedWithoutATaggedTicket" : 0,
        "gamesStarted" : 0,
        "lastAppLogin" : 1.531419079470824E12,
        "lastGamePlayed" : 0,
        "uid" : "zo9KcrXXXXXXXmSv8Cc8W2XeCb2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I change the query to an Observe query instead of ObserveSingleEvent, and then write a single value to the database using 'updateChildValues', the observe closure log messages show up in the logs twice.  The first time (before my write), I get Null for snapshot.value and the second time (after my UpdateChildValues post), snapshot.value contains ALL of the correct data.

Can anyone help me understand why I am seeing the Null value or point out what I'm doing wrong?  All I want to do is retrieve the information from the key one time so I can initialize some local objects.  I am new to Swift and Firebase so it is completely possible - even likely - that I've misunderstood something pretty fundamental here.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: observeSingleEvent doesn't really work the way you are expecting.  Look into using keepSynced or you can just use the observe function and remove the observer once the fresh data is pulled to have a similar effect. - Side note if you are just starting with Firebase you should look into Cloud Firestore over Realtime database.